# Как задать условие ввода 2 чисел после запятой в EditText?

Tags: java, android

Есть поле ввода суммы `EditText` с типом `"numberDecimal"`.

Проблема в том что после запятой можно ставить много чисел, а мне надо не больше 2 (копейки).

Как задать условие чтобы после запятой было не больше 2 символов?

**UPD:** Пока вменяемых ответов нет, ковырял сам и сделал следующее:

```
    etSumm.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            //Переменная результата
            Boolean res = false;
            //Считываем что находится в EditText
            String str = etSumm.getText().toString();
            //Узнаем какой символ был нажат
            char c = keyEvent.getDisplayLabel();
            //Преобразуем символ в строку, для сравнения
            String sc = String.valueOf(c);
            //Если нажата точка и она не первая в строке - разрешаем поставить
            if (sc.equals(".") && str.length() > 0 ){
                res = false;
            }//Если точки нет и входящий символ не точка - разрешаем поставить
            else if (str.indexOf(".") == -1  && !sc.equals(".")) {
                res = false;
            }//Если точка не первый символ и после нее не больше 2 символов - разрешаем ввод
            else if ((str.indexOf(".") > 0) && (str.lastIndexOf(".") >= str.length() - 2)) {
                res = false;
            } else {//В остальных случаях - запрещаем ввод
                res = true;
            }
            return res;
        }
    });
```

Возможно есть какой-то более гуманный способ, предложенный Google? Очень удивило что нет типа клавы для ввода денег, или есть? )

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636444/edittext-showing-numbers-with-2-decimals-at-all-times - вот, похожий вопрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В `EditText` c атрибутом `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` ввести запятую у меня не получается, но можно ввести точку (видимо зависит от локального десятичного разделителя).

Вот Вам пример с точкой:

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String str = s.toString();
        int p = str.indexOf(".");
        if (p != -1) {
            String tmpStr = str.substring(p);
            if (tmpStr.length() == 4) {
                s.delete(s.length()-1, s.length());
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Здесь используется интерфейс `TextWatcher`, который позволяет следить за вводом в `EditText`. В методе `afterTextChanged(...)` проверяется текущее содержимое `EditText`, если после очередного ввода получаем третий знак после точки, то этот знак удаляется из `EditText`.

Comment: Согласен, Ваш вариант слушателя лучше и правильней, я еще добавил проверку на то чтоб точка не была первой в строке.

Answer (score 0):

За основу взят ответ post_zeew и добавлена проверка на точку как первый символ в строке

```
etSumm.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            //Считываем вводимый текст
            String str = editable.toString();
            //Узнаем позицию
            int position = str.indexOf(".");
            //Если точка есть делаем проверки
            if (position != -1) {
                //Отрезаем кусок строки начиная с точки и до конца строки
                String subStr = str.substring(position);
                //Отрезаем строку с начала и до точки
                String subStrStart = str.substring(0, position);
                //Если символов после точки больше чем 3 или если точка первая в строке - удаляем последний
                if (subStr.length() > 3 || subStrStart.length() == 0) {
                    editable.delete(editable.length() - 1, editable.length());
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Может будет кому-то полезно.